# css get width and background to fill viewport

Tags: css

hey hoping someone can help me. It's for my portfolio I'm building at www.pxlmin.com/portfolio

What I want is for the background color to take up the whole width, and it does, but when I resize the window down-to say half the width-I just get white space off to the side, (when I scroll to the right), so what I'm wondering is how can I get the background of both the center and the container to extend off to the left.. I have width 100% but it's obviously not doing the trick. Thanks.

Comment: probably need a bit code or something here - hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: matpol, please view source at the link I provided. Firebug, works nice..

Comment: 100% width is most likely making the background just the browser side. Meaning if you have to scroll either way you will run into white. Set the background on the .body and remove any height or width properties

Comment: hey tony, thanks yeah it's weird. I just put the background on body, as suggested by the guy bellow, and removed the width 100%-which didn't fix it- but you'd think there's a way to get an internal div to inherit the whole width of the screen. (when sizing down the width of the window).

Comment: right now only problem is getting the div #middleport to fill the whole width of the screen, when you size down the viewport area and scroll to the right.

Comment: weird stuff..maybe a background on body is the only solution, although definitely not ideal.. I just noticed tinygrab.com has the same problem. just size down the width of your window and scroll to the right, background falls right off..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahha, figured it out.. just set a min-width greater than the amount of the content you need to fill with the background. in my case div #middleport min-width: 1500px;

Amazing the amount of pages that have these fall off backgrounds though (when viewport width reduced and scolled to the right).. tinygrab.com, nodejs.org to name a couple..

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 100%;` from `#portContainer and #middlePort`. Hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: hi Subhajit, no didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the main background color to the body tag:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #EFE6D9
}
```

or use a background image which has the stripes in - but as the above remove the 100% width or set the left and right borders to 0. The white bit is probably 6 pixels which is the the borders being added to the width.

```
#middlePort {
background: #E8DED0;
height: 300px;
border: 3px solid #E2DAD0;
padding-top: 49px;
}
```

or

```
#middlePort {
background: #E8DED0;
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 3px solid  #E2DAD0;
border-top: 3px solid  #E2DAD0;
padding-top: 49px;
}
```

Comment: hey so background is fixed, only issue now is to get div #middleport to fill the screen, when you size down the width of the window.